# Android: Can't use android.R.drawable as background image for textview

Tags: android, background, textview, drawable

I'm trying to use the android.R.drawable stat_sys_download as the background image for a text view but it's not showing up:

```
textview.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download));
```

If I use a different android.R.drawable like ic_menu_save it works fine:

```
textview.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save));
```

I can however use stat_sys_download as an icon on a menu option so I know it exists:

```
menu.add(0, OPTION_MENU_SORTBY, 0, Str.TEXT_SORTBY).setIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download);
```

So why is it that I can use stat_sys_download as an icon but not as a background? Should I copy it into my resources folder and use it that way?

Comment: What happens if you copy the drawable.stat_sys_download into your local folder and then use yourpackage.R.drawable.stat_sys_download instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Google's UI Guidelines for Status Bar Icons](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html) (also can be applied towards other drawable elements)

> Warning: Because these resources can change between platform versions,
>   you should not reference these icons using the Android platform
>   resource IDs (i.e. status bar icons under android.R.drawable). If you
>   want to use any icons or other internal drawable resources, you should
>   store a local copy of those icons or drawables in your application
>   resources, then reference the local copy from your application code.
>   In that way, you can maintain control over the appearance of your
>   icons, even if the system's copy changes.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, though there's probably a difference between ic_menu_save and stat_sys_download in their formats which causes this problem. Can you try using `setBackgroundResource(int resId)` instead? Otherwise, try copying the resource to your local directory and see if that works.